# How can I add CSS animation to an element on a web page?

Tags: css, css-animations

I want to add animation to a label on my page to "speed up" the loading of the page (distract the user). I would like my h1 label to morph through the colors of the rainbow (ROYGBIV).

What is the simplest way to accomplish this using HTML and CSS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give your h1 label a class, such as "Rainbojangles":

```
<h1 class="Rainbojangles">Award Winners Only</h1>
```

Include that class in your Site.css (or other CSS) file:

```
.Rainbojangles {
    color: white;
    font-size: 2em;
    font-family: 'Segoe UI Light', Candara, Consolas, Calibri, sans-serif !important;
    text-shadow: 4px 3px 6px #000000;
    text-shadow: 4px 3px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
    display: inline;
    padding-right: 10px;

    animation-name: rainbowGlow;
    animation-duration: 5s;
    animation-delay: 2s;
    -moz-animation: rainbowGlow 5s 1 linear;
    -o-animation: rainbowGlow  5s 1 linear;
    -webkit-animation: rainbowGlow 5s 1 linear;
    animation: rainbowGlow 5s 1 linear;
}
```

(the first section of class rules are can be tweaked or removed); the animation section of rules are what is absolutely needed)

Add the animation code to the CSS file:

```
@-webkit-keyframes rainbowGlow {
from {
         color: white;
     }
13% {
        color: red;
    }
25% {
        color: orange;
    }
38% {
        color: yellow;
    }
50% {
        color: green;
    }
63% {
        color: blue;
    }
75% {
        color: indigo;
    }
88% {
        color: violet;
    }
to {
       color: white;
   }
}
```

As you can see, I start with white and return to white, but in-between that cycle through the colors of the rainbow, giving approximately equal "weight" to each hue.

Note, though, that in addition to "@-webkit-keyframes rainbowGlow", you will also need the same CSS with:

```
@-moz-keyframes rainbowGlow 
@-o-keyframes rainbowGlow 
@keyframes rainbowGlow
```

...to support as many browsers as possible.

To see this CSS3 rainbow animation in action, check it out at http://www.awardwinnersonly.com/

Comment: You posted a question and answered it yourself a minute later? Is this just an attempt to get us to visit your site?

Comment: That is actually one of the intended usages of Stack Overflow, as a sort of tip repository.

Comment: It is, but your questions is off-topic: "Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results."